# Adding checkcolumn by ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a tabpanel and want add `GridPanel` in one Tab.
In this gridPanel i have a few colums, and one of this colums gonna contain checkboxes. But i cant add this.
Im do this.

```
        xtype: 'checkcolumn',
        header: '',
        dataIndex: 'indoor',
        width: 50
```

And in FireBug get this

```
l is not a constructor


...ng(this.enableUrlEncode)?this.enableUrlEncode:"data"]=Ext.encode(h);k.params=l}e...

ext-al...9641744 (line 1)
```

What i doing wrong?

Comment: That looks like JSON. Wrap it in `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no type named `checkcolumn`,you can change to `checkboxfield`. hope it can help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to include that file in your page. Just download it and place it somewhere like this

```
<script src="/Libraries/Ext/ux/checkcolumn.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    xtype: 'checkboxfield',
    header: '',
    dataIndex: 'indoor',
    width: 50
```

Comment: In this example all works fine   http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/grid/edit-grid.html  http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/grid/edit-grid.js

Comment: You need create Data Store with `{name: 'indoor', type: 'bool'}` and create the column model `{
            xtype: 'checkcolumn',
            header: 'Indoor?',
            dataIndex: 'indoor'`

Comment: `fields: [`
   `{name: 'indoor', type: 'bool'},`
   `{name: 'kad_name',type: 'string'},`
   `{name: 'kad_id', type: 'integer'}`
  `]`

Comment: In really i need to include this plugin http://trac.geoext.org/browser/ext/3.2.1/examples/ux/CheckColumn.js?rev=2155 in application but how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

set Ext ux path at the begining .
Or inclucded 'CheckColumn.js' where is in Ext ux folder in your script . It works!

> 